Why does Ktor server 3.0.0 wraps BadRequestException into its copy when Ktor started within jUnit test?
Consider the following minimal build configuration:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "2.0.21"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.3.12" // or "3.0.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.11")

    val jUnitVersion = "5.11.3"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$jUnitVersion")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$jUnitVersion")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host-jvm")
}

tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}

with the following Ktor app's code (Application.kt):
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, module = Application::module).start(wait = true)
}

@Suppress("unused")
fun Application.module() {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
    routing {
        post("/articles") {
            @Serializable
            data class Article(val title: String, val isPublished: Boolean = false)
            try {
                call.receive<Article>()
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                call.respond(
                    status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    message = e.exceptionChain
                )
            }
            call.respond("")
        }
    }
}

val Throwable.exceptionChain: String
    get() = buildString {
        append(this@exceptionChain::class.simpleName)
        var e: Throwable? = this@exceptionChain.cause
        while (e != null) {
            append(" -> ${e::class.simpleName}")
            e = e.cause
        }
    }

and the following jUnit 5 test which simply starts main method from Application.kt and never finishes:
class TrickyExceptionTest {
    @Test
    fun mainTest() {
        main()
    }
}

If you simply run the app (let's say with ./gradlew :run or by running the main method in Intellij) and do:
POST http://localhost:8080/articles
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "title": "Hello",
  "isPublished": "falsey"
}

... then the exceptions chain thrown from call.receive<Article>() will be: BadRequestException -> JsonConvertException -> JsonDecodingException (that's expected).
If you run the app through the above jUnit 5 test, the exception stacktrace becomes:
BadRequestException -> BadRequestException -> JsonConvertException -> JsonDecodingException

Notice the double BadRequestException. That's not expected.
First of all, I'd like to understand why this happens. Previously I used embeddedServer(...).start() in my test codebase to conduct e2e testing. Now with the major upgrade of Ktor from 2.x to 3.0.0, I'm facing this issue and tests are failing, because production code relying on JsonConvertException to be the cause of BadRequestException no longer works (JsonConvertException is now one level deeper in the chain when the app gets executed under e2e test suite).
Is this rather a bug in Ktor 3.0.0 or something which works as expected but I don't understand?
Below are the stacktraces difference produced by e.printStackTrace() line.
For Ktor 2.x the stacktrace was:
io.ktor.server.plugins.BadRequestException: Illegal input: Unexpected JSON token at offset 45: Expected closing quotation mark at path: $.isPublished
JSON input: {
  "title": "Hello",
  "isPublished": "falsey"
}
    at _COROUTINE._BOUNDARY._(CoroutineDebugging.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.server.request.ApplicationReceiveFunctionsKt.receiveNullable(ApplicationReceiveFunctions.kt:103)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt$module$2$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:60)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.Route$buildPipeline$1$1.invokeSuspend(Route.kt:116)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:478)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:188)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.Routing$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:140)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationEngineKt$installDefaultTransformationChecker$1.invokeSuspend(BaseApplicationEngine.kt:124)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:478)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:123)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:478)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:140)
Caused by: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Unexpected JSON token at offset 45: Expected closing quotation mark at path: $.isPublished
JSON input: {
  "title": "Hello",
  "isPublished": "falsey"
}
    at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.KotlinxSerializationConverter.deserialize(KotlinxSerializationConverter.kt:90)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt.convertBody(RequestConverter.kt:67)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt.access$convertBody(RequestConverter.kt:1)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invokeSuspend(RequestConverter.kt:40)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invoke(RequestConverter.kt)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invoke(RequestConverter.kt)
    at io.ktor.server.application.OnCallReceiveContext.transformBody(KtorCallContexts.kt:65)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1.invokeSuspend(RequestConverter.kt:28)
...

For Ktor 3.0.0 it has become:
io.ktor.server.plugins.BadRequestException: Failed to convert request body to class com.example.ApplicationKt$module$2$1$Article
    at _COROUTINE._BOUNDARY._(CoroutineDebugging.kt:42)
    at io.ktor.server.application.PipelineCall$DefaultImpls.receiveNullable(PipelineCall.kt:92)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt$module$2$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:59)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.RoutingNode$buildPipeline$1$1.invokeSuspend(RoutingNode.kt:116)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:490)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.RoutingRoot.executeResult(RoutingRoot.kt:191)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.RoutingRoot.interceptor(RoutingRoot.kt:66)
    at io.ktor.server.routing.RoutingRoot$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(RoutingRoot.kt:143)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationEngineKt$installDefaultTransformationChecker$1.invokeSuspend(BaseApplicationEngine.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:490)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:123)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.PipelineKt$execute$2.invokeSuspend(Pipeline.kt:490)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:140)
Caused by: io.ktor.server.plugins.BadRequestException: Failed to convert request body to class com.example.ApplicationKt$module$2$1$Article
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt.convertBody(RequestConverter.kt:69)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt.access$convertBody(RequestConverter.kt:1)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invokeSuspend(RequestConverter.kt:40)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invoke(RequestConverter.kt)
    at io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.RequestConverterKt$convertRequestBody$1$1.invoke(RequestConverter.kt)
    at io.ktor.server.application.OnCallReceiveContext.transformBody(KtorCallContexts.kt:64)
... + JsonConvertException etc...

Another interesting observation, which I have while building the minimal setup to reproduce the problem, is that the following test passes with the latest Ktor 2.x (v2.3.12), but exactly the same test will fail if you run the test in Intellij debug mode (without changing Ktor version).
@Test
fun lightweightKtorTest() = testApplication {
    val response = client.post("/articles") {
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        setBody("""{"title": "Hello", "isPublished": "invalid-value"}""")
    }
    assertEquals("BadRequestException -> JsonConvertException -> JsonDecodingException", response.bodyAsText())
}


This seems to be a bug, so I've filed an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-7654).

@AlekseiTirman thank you! What do you think about exception wrapping in Intellij debug mode in Ktor v2.3.12? also a bug?

What do you mean by the IntelliJ debug mode?

@AlekseiTirman in the end of this post there is an example of testApplication {...} test, which fails even with Ktor 2.x if you run it from Intellij using debug icon.

It most likely has something to do with the additional debug context when debugging an application in IntelliJ IDEA (https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/acff41d54dc84af1c437c950c6f8b5142f7a099b/ktor-utils/common/src/io/ktor/util/debug/ContextUtils.kt)

@AlekseiTirman yeah, seems like it's true. But would you expect that exception wrapping or another bug should be submitted?

Feel free to file an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=ktor) if you think it's a bug
